# how to do data migration from Joomla to WebSphere Portal?

Tags: websphere-portal

we current having a project that need to use data migration from joomla to WebSphere Portal.. but i can't find any resource on how will I'll do it. Can anyone help me??

https://docs.joomla.org/Planning_for_Migration
i only found this reference but it on how to migrate to another server not into websphere portal
http://pbwebdev.com/blog/migrating-joomla-websites-to-a-new-server

can anyone give me more reference on how to do data migration from Joomla to WebSphere Portal?

Answer (score 0):

If your able to keep the Joomla server around I would use the WAI integration to pretend it's a portlet/page on websphere portal.

Otherwise it could be quite painful to port.

[More details on WAI](https://greenhouse.lotus.com/plugins/plugincatalog.nsf/assetDetails.xsp?action=editDocument&documentId=31AC15EF8BF546DF85257700005C50BE)